# dpkt doesn't generate tcp object

Tags: python

Try to use dpkt to parse a pcap. Got the following sample code but it gave errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "te.py", line 14, in <module>
    print tcp.sport
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sport'
```

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, python 2.7.6.  Installed module "dpkt" using "pip", but not sure what's the version on dpkt.

```
#examples
#   https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/
#   https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/944167-dpkt-parsing-pcap-file
import dpkt
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data
    print tcp.sport
f.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure only TCP packets were captured?

Comment: Thanks for the question that led to the realization that the first two packets are ARP and the rest are TCP packets.

Answer (score 0):

The two comments are true. The packets that you read from as no link layer (like TCP or UDP).
Therefore, before you read the next layer in the packet, check if it exists.

This will help you:

```
# Check for TCP or UDP packets
if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP or ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
```

In your example it looks like this:

```
import dpkt
import sys

f = open("email1b.pcap")
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
     
     # Check if there is TCP in packet
     if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
        tcp = ip.data
        print tcp.sport

     else:
        print "there is no TCP in the packet"

f.close()
```